# Stack linkedlist with initial Capacity

Tags: java, list, linked-list, stack, capacity

I am doing a stack using LinkedList and LinearNode Class in Java and I have a problem:

........

```
public BoundedStackADTLinkedImpl() {
        count = 0;
        top = null;
    }

public BoundedStackADTLinkedImpl(int stackCapacity) {
//I dont know how to do a builder using LinearNode with a initial Capacity  
}
    public BoundedStackADTLinkedImpl(int stackCapacity, T... initialContent) {
//Here I have the same problem.
    count = 0;
    top = new LinearNode<T>();
    for (T Vi : initialContent) {

        push(Vi);
    }
```

........

thanks!!!

Comment: Please say a little bit more about your problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal testable code.

Comment: A LinkedList only has the nodes you are actually using so an initial capacity is meaningless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why LinkedList doesn't have initialCapacity in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050211/why-linkedlist-doesnt-have-initialcapacity-in-java)

Comment: thanks for your answers i only have an interface and i think that i have to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LinkedList` allocate a memory when item is added in it. There is no meaning of initial capacity. Each item has a pointer to next item.

Why don't you use [Stack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) that has a [ensureCapacity()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#ensureCapacity%28int%29) method?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this for a linked list.  Just remember, you can't set initial capacity, as capacity is determined by the number of elements in the list, you don't pre-create space for them.

```
public class LinkedList<T>
{
Node<T> topNode = null;

public LinkedList()
{
}

public LinkedList( Node<T>... nodes )
{
    for( Node<T> n : nodes )
    {
        push( n );
    }
}

public void push(Node<T> node)
{
    if ( topNode == null )
    {
        topNode = node;
        return;
    }

    Node<T> n = topNode;
    while( n.nextNode != null )
    {
        n = n.nextNode;
    }

    n.nextNode = node;
}

public Node<T> pop()
{
    if ( topNode != null )
    {
        Node<T> n = topNode;
        Node<T> p = n;
        while( n.nextNode != null )
        {
            n = n.nextNode;
            if ( n.nextNode != null )
            {
                p = n;
            }
        }

        p.nextNode = null;
        return n;
    }

    return null;
}
}

class Node <T>
{
Node<T> nextNode = null;
T value;

public Node( T val )
{
    value = val;
}
}
```